# samba4 no access to share over domain name on win7

Tags: windows-7, share, samba4

i have installed and configured samba4 on ubuntu 14.04 and Remote Server Administration Tools on a fresh Windows7 (client).

Samba4 is configured as a Domain Controller with DNS.

On Win7, when I open Explorer and enter the URL "\\domain name\" I can **SEE** ALL the shares, but I can only access to the 'default' folders "netlogon" and "sysvol". After clicking on the other folders, an error dialog pops up with "You cant access to \\domain name\share_name. You maybe dont have permission blabla..."(translated).

**BUT** when I open Explorer and enter the URL "\\computer name\" then I can **SEE** and **ACCESS** to ALL the folders.

As you can see, im able to access to shares over the computer name of the server, but not over the dns name. Any suggestions on fixing this behaviour ?

Thanks in advice,
testuser

Comment: if you can resolve same computer with dns names (not ip), then there is no DNS problems. Did you look into samba log files? If there is nothing interesting, try increasing log level. After rebooting windows 7 machine, domain name & computer name hassle still exists? Win7 machine is in domain? or you are authenticating when first time access samba?

Comment: @Guntis When I try to access the share, in the log.smbd it says:  "get_referred_path: |Test| in dfs path \ADS\Test is not a dfs root.", where Test is the sharefolder name and ADS is the domain name

Comment: please answer other question too

Comment: @Guntis Win7 machine is also in the domain and I logged in as ADS\administrator. What exactly do you mean with "DN & CN hassle" and with "authenticating when first time access samba" ?

Comment: did you try to google `get_referred_path: is not a dfs root.` ? And did you try to reboot win7 machine?

Comment: @Guntis IT WORKS NOW! I googled for this message and it said to add "host msdfs = no" to smb.conf. after reloading samba (smdcontrol all reload-config) and rebooting client, I am now able to connect to the shares. Thank you